What writing system are they using in "The Hidden Dungeon Only I Can Enter"?
What language or writing system are the characters using in the anime, "The Hidden Dungeon Only I Can Enter"?
For Example:





Is it just a made up language and writing system or is it based off of any existing language and writing system?

Some of it is just a fancy font.
Rare Shop Starjia

Noir (to) Alice no Him(i)ts(u) (no) Kob(e)y(a)
(Bracketed letters are omitted in the fancy font, but present in the Japanese subtitles.)

Other parts seem to be gibberish.
Between the two 1s and the two 2s you can see the same character being repeated three times each, for example.


That last one is the romaji without vowels (in fancy font).

K(o)r(e) yor(i)s(hi)r(e)n g(a) k(o)t(o)n(a)r(u)
1-n(i)n n(a)r(a) 1
2-n(i)n ij(ou) n(a)r(a) 2 n(i) s(u)s(u)m(e)
